# age calculator with the user inputting the birth and current year using assembly language

Tags: assembly

```
DOSSEG
    .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA

UserName db "Name: $"
CLRF     db 10,13,"$"
inputName db 24 dup ("$")

CurYear db "Current Year: $"
inputCurrentYear db 8 dup ("$")

BirYear   db "Birth Year: $"
inputBirthYear db 8 dup ("$")   

outputName db "Hello, $"

.code
BEGIN:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax

mov al,03h
mov ah, 00h
int 10h

;username input

NameInput:
lea dx,UserName
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov inputName,21
lea dx,inputName
mov ah,0ah
int 21h

lea dx,CLRF
mov ah,09h
int 21h

;current year

CurrentYear:
lea dx,CurYear
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov inputCurrentYear,05
lea dx,inputCurrentYear
mov ah,0ah
int 21h

lea dx,CLRF
mov ah,09h
int 21h

;birth year

BirthYear:
lea dx,BirYear
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov inputBirthYear,05
lea dx,inputBirthYear
mov ah,0ah
int 21h

lea dx,CLRF
mov ah,09h
int 21h

;subtraction

mov eax, inputCurrentYear
mov ebx ,inputBirthYear
sub eax,ebx



Output:
lea dx, outputName
mov ah,09h
int 21h

lea dx, inputName
mov ah,09h
int 21h

lea dx,CLRF
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
end BEGIN
```

I need help because I don't know how to convert the output into a decimal value

Comment: the "value" of the number will be identical, no matter whether its representation is hex or binary or decimal. You probably want something else than "decimal value"

Answer (score 0):

Also the inputs of the decimal ASCIIs have to be converted for calculating. The first step for that is to substract 30h from all of the decimal ASCII numbers and the second step is to multiplicate the digits of that full value of all of the single digits for a base ten number system. Example the second lowest digit have to be multiplicate by ten, the third lowest digit have to be multiplicate by 100 and so on. Finally we have to add all values together. And now we can work with this value.

For a decimal output we have to divide and to split the number into seperate digits and than we have to add to all of that 30h for to convert it to ASCIIs. Example if the value is decimal 1995, than we have to divide this value by decimal 1000 for to seperate the highest digit of 1. And then we have to divide the value again by 100 for to seperate the 9 and so on.

Comment: we don't "have to", there are more elegant approaches, employing successive modulo division by radix. Those approaches would call for intermediate buffering (because string is generated "backwards"), but this buffering can be done on stack, using recursion to generate, and outputting when backtracing from recursion.

Comment: Ok we don't "have to", sorry for my unfelicitous words, but anyhow we want to get a result, also if different ways for calculating exist. ...Personally i like it more to use the data segment for buffering values, because the data segment can be easier access, without to care about the stackpointer inside and outside subroutines and the addresses can be simple declared with an own name.

Comment: no names needed, and no explicite buffer space allocation, also no need to "care" about stackpointer - push while recursing into conversion, pull and output when unwinding. how would data segment be easier to access than simply pushing or pulling from stack? first pushed item will be last to get pulled, last pushed item is first to get pulled - result is reversal of order between generating and outputting characters

Comment: Mostly i used a stacksize of only 16 bytes and if i want to store some more bytes on the stack, then i have to allocate more space for the stack. And if we want to access some values later again from outside and/or deep inside of nested subroutines, then we have to care about the stackpointer. And if we want to use assembler for to get a faster working code, then the older x86 before pentium 4 benefit most, if we use the mov instruction for moving a value to and from the ram instead of using the instuction pair of push and pop, because the mov instruction execute faster on older x86-CPUs.